# How to assign the same value in certain block with PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here , I want to assign all the value of `router_index` in the same block with the first row of index value in this block.

E.g. The `router_index` value from Row 1 to 4 should be `5,383` and from 5 to 7 should be `2,703`...

I wonder if I can do it with pure PostgreSQL ?

Thanks for your help!!!!

[image]

Comment: Tables in a relational database represent unordered sets. There is no such thing as "Row 1 to 4" in a relational database unless you have something you can sort the rows by. So what you are trying to achieve is essentially impossible in a predictable manner unless you have a column that you can use for an `ORDER BY` to define the order of the rows. As all your sample rows share the same `driver_index_code` there is no reliable (stable) way to distinguish "row 2" from "row 6". If you run the same SELECT statement later "row 6" could become "row 3" or even "row 1"

Comment: What is a "block"?  Nothing in your question defines this.

Answer (score 0):

```
do $$
declare 
    cnt integer := 0;
    head_index_id varchar := '0';
    cur_index_id varchar := '0';
    fixed_index varchar := '10';
    cnt_limit integer;
begin
    select max(per_id) from detailed_router into cnt_limit;
    while cnt <= cnt_limit loop
        select router_index from detailed_router where per_id = cnt into    cur_index_id;
    
        if head_index_id = '0' and cur_index_id != fixed_index then
            head_index_id := cur_index_id;
        else
            if cur_index_id = fixed_index then
                -- update
                update detailed_router set router_index = head_index_id where per_id = cnt;
            else
                select router_index from detailed_router where per_id = cnt into head_index_id; 
            end if;
        end if;

        raise notice 'cnt %', cnt;
        raise notice 'cur_index_id %', cur_index_id;
        raise notice 'head_index_id %', head_index_id;
        cnt := cnt + 1;
    end loop;
    

end $$
```

Comment: This code shows that a column ***does*** exist that can be used to enforce an order on the data *(`per_id`)*.  Please edit your question to include that column in your question's example data.  *(Also, please include example data as formatted text, not images.)*

Answer (score 0):

If you want "10" values to be filled with the previous non-"10" value *and* you have a column that specifies the ordering, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       max(router_index) over (partition by driver_index_code, grp) as imputed_router_index
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where router_index > 10) over (partition by driver_index_code order by <ordering column>) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```